Weyl equidistribution for a periodic $L^2$ function
Let $\alpha $ be a fixed irrational number. For a function $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$, define $$g^*(x)=\sup_{N\geq 1} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N |g(x+\alpha n)| ,$$
and assume that there is a constant $C>0$ such that $$ m(\{x\in [0,1]:g^*(x)>a\})\leq \frac{C}{a} ||g||_{L^1[0,1]} ~~~\cdots (*)$$
for any $a>0$ and 1-periodic function $g$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. I am trying to prove that for any 1-periodic $f\in L^2[0,1]$, $$\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N f(x+\alpha n)=\int_0^1 f(y) ~dy$$
almost everywhere. I've shown this when $f=e^{2\pi i mx}$ ($m\in \Bbb Z$) by direct calculation, so this also holds for linear combination of $e^{2\pi i mx}$'s, i.e. for trigonometric functions. Since continuous functions on $[0,1]$ can be approximated by trigonometric functions, the result holds for continuous functions on $[0,1]$. Until now, I haven't used the condition $(*)$, so it seems that to show that the result holds for arbitrary 1-periodic $L^2[0,1]$-function, the condition $(*)$ is needed, but I can't see how. Any hints?
My attempt. Let $f$ be a 1-periodic function in $L^2[0,1]$ and let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Since $L^2[0,1]\subset L^1[0,1]$, and since continuous functions are dense in $L^1[0,1]$, we can choose continuous $g\in L^1[0,1]$ such that $||f-g||_{L^1}<\epsilon$. We may assume $g$ is 1-periodic. Then we have \begin{align*} \bigg|\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N f(x+\alpha n) -\int_0^1 f(y) ~dy\bigg| & \leq \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N |f(x+\alpha n ) -g(x+\alpha n)| \\
 & ~~ + \int_0^1 |f(y)-g(y)|~dy  \\
& ~~ + \bigg| \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N g(x+\alpha n) -\int_0^1 g(y) ~dy\bigg| \\
& < (f-g)^*(x)+2\epsilon \end{align*}
for $N$ large. Maybe I should use $(*)$ here, but how?

What you are trying to prove is true for any $f\in L^1$, it is the content of the pointwise ergodic theorem, as the transformation $x\mapsto x+\alpha$ in the torus is ergodic

Another remark - $L^2 \cap L^1$ is dense in $L^1$, hence using the maximal inequality, you are left with showing the result for $L^2$($\cap L^1$) functions...
